# One contact not recieving SMS messages

Tags: samsung, sms

There is one contact who I text and call regularly cannot receive SMS messages from my phone. They can receive calls and MMS messages. Forcing MMS costs too much on my network plan so is unfeasible. All other contacts recieve SMS messages perfectly. All kinds of restarts have been tried on both ends.
I am stuck with where to go.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: They haven't accidentally blocked texts from you?  And before your say they can receive calls from you, text and calls are blocked separately on some phones

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't have anything to do with Android specifically. You might want to contact your provider instead to troubleshoot this.